# Sync Contacts between iPhones with different Apple IDs

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts, apple-id

Until recently my wife and I shared one Apple ID to allow us to have synced calendars and contacts.  The only thing she used her ID for was the Messages app.  When I learned that I could set her phone up with both of our IDs and then choose which one it pulls from for each item I changed to this approach.  So now the only things turned on for my ID on her phone are Calendars and Contacts.

This works great other than on her phone under the "Contacts" heading of "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" it has my info selected.  If she changes it on her phone it will update mine as well.

Does anyone have a better solution for how we can sync our contacts book (other than using a 3rd-party service like Google)?  Thanks.

-James

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the Apple Forums explained that I need to turn on Contacts for both Apple ID accounts on my wife's phone.  This will allow us to have different "My Info" cards while still syncing contact changes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a husband and wife want to share contacts. In `Settings > iCloud`, the husband adds his account. In it, he must sync contacts; he can also sync whatever else he wants.

In `Settings > iCloud`, the wife adds her account. In it, she cannot sync contacts, but she can sync whatever else she wants. In `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars`, she adds her husband's account. In it, the only thing she syncs is contacts.

This answer is a dupe of [How do I sync contacts between 2 iCloud accounts with iOS 8?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148301/how-do-i-sync-contacts-between-2-icloud-accounts-with-ios-8/148364#148364).

Comment: James, if this is a duplicate, please mark the question as so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to iCloud.com with first Apple ID, go to Contacts, select all contacts, then use Settings in the bottom left corner to invoke Export as vCard. Remember the directory where you saved the vCard file.
2. Sign out of the iCloud.com
3. Sign in to iCloud using another Apple ID account where you want to copy the contacts.
4. Go to Contacts, click on Settings and invoke Import vCard, point to the directory where you saved Contacts in step 1, this should import all the contacts to the second account.
5. Just wait, on the device with second Apple ID the Contacts will shortly appear.